# Printing tree list tuple elements in F#

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, c#-to-f#

I have a simple tree structure like this..

```
type Tree<'a,'b> = 
    | Node of list<'a * Tree<'a,'b>>
    | Leaf of 'b

let phonebook = Node["MyPhonebook",
                     Node["Work",
                          Node["Company1", Node["Employee1", Leaf("phone#")];
                               "Company2", Leaf("phone#")];
                          "Private",
                          Node["Family", Node["Brother", Leaf("phone#");]; "Sister", Leaf("phone#")]
                         ]
                    ]
```

Im simply trying to print root folders (Work, Private) of this phone book but cant seem to get it right whatever I do...

```
let listelements tree =
    match tree with
    | Node[a, b] -> // OK - root node
        printfn "%s" a // OK - root folder name
        match b with
        //| _ -> printf "%A" b // OK - prints whole node
        | Node[a, b] -> printf "%A" a // Match failure!

listelements phonebook
```

After that I realized I've been matching tuple with list so I tried something a bit different but i get missmatches again.

```
let phonebook = [Node["Work",
                      Node["Company1", Node["Employee1", Leaf("phone#")];
                           "Company2", Leaf("phone#")];
                      "Private",
                      Node["Family", Node["Brother", Leaf("phone#");]; "Sister", Leaf("phone#")]
                     ]
                 ]

let listelements tree =
    for i in tree do
        match i with
        | Node[a, b] -> printf "%s" a // Match fail

let listelements tree =
    //tree |> List.iter (fun x -> printf "%A" x) // OK - prints nodes
    tree |> List.iter (fun x ->
        match x with
        | Node[a, b] -> printf "%A" a) // Match fail
```

What the hell am I doing wrong here? There has to be a more elegant and simple way to do this. I come from C# and this is driving me insane :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are matching a list of a single element (a tuple) against a List, so in the first case the list contains only one element and it pass though the compiler warns you that the matching is incomplete.
But in the second match the list contains two tuples, so it fails.

Use instead a head::tail pattern, like this:

```
| Node((a, b)::xs)
```

or if you are not interested in the tail at all:

```
| Node((a, b)::_)
```

**NOTE**

Something that will help to clarify your code: tree is a list of tuples as from the definition. It's better if you write  the pattern making the parenthesis of the tuple explicit, I mean if you write:

```
| Node[(a, b)] ->
```

instead of just

```
| Node[a, b] ->
```

Here the compiler understand that is a tuple, but a human may not, especially if it comes from a Haskell background.

So, writing the parenthesis will probably help you to figure out that the problem is that you are matching agains a list with only one tuple.

**UPDATE**

If you want to print all elements using `List.iter`:

```
let rec listelements tree =
    let printNode (a, b) = 
        printfn "%s" a
        listelements b
    match tree with
    | Leaf leaf         -> printfn "Leaf %s" leaf
    | Node(listOfNodes) -> List.iter printNode listOfNodes
```

Comment: I realized I was matching tuple against a list so I remove root tuple and made the whole phonebook a list as posted in question update.

Comment: I tried with let listelements tree = tree |> List.iter (fun x -> match x with | Node((a, b)::_/xs) -> printf "%s" a) but only first node gets printed?

Comment: No, that wasn't the problem. You were not matching a tuple against a list. You were matching a List of a (single) tuple against a List of (any number of) tuples. And the problem remains the same, just change the pattern to the one I'm suggesting and it will match.

Comment: Oh... Ok, but this missmatches again at runtime: | Node[(a, b)] -> printf "%A %A" a b

Comment: Of course. It's just to clarify, but if you want to solve it, add the tail of the list as I suggested from the beginning: | Node((a, b)::xs)

Comment: But if I use that for matching only first list element gets printed like I said. I suppose i have to iterate through the remainder of the list but how exactly?

Comment: Yes, if you want more elements you need to iterate. Try using recursion for the rest.

Comment: I did so like in my second comment but still... just first element.

Comment: Thank you. I was actually just interested in correct code for matching and iteration through the list without in depth recursion. But this works for me when I omit recursion call.